# Regex replace problem with (mostly) string content

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm trying to wrap all occurrences of an IP address with an HREF so I can then Do Stuff(tm).

I've run the regex itself through several validators, and it matches pattern as expected.  Therefore, I'm thinking my problem is in the implementation, but I can't see the correct path.  Can anyone help out?

Here's the regex and relevant code:

```
var theIps = new RegExp('^((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})$','g');  
var newBody = jQuery('#ELEMENT').html();  
var processed = newBody.replace(theIps, '<a class="ipPopup" href="javascript:void(0)" rel="10.5.1.2"    onclick="addToWatchlist(this)">TESTING REGEX</a>');  
jQuery('#ELEMENT').html(processed);
```

Thanks in advance for any assistance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regex syntax for your regex:

```
var theIps = /^((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})$/g;
```

When you build the RegExp object from a string, you have to double the backslashes. If the regular expression is constant (i.e., you're not building it up dynamically) then it's easier to use the "native" syntax.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply -- and for fixing my post :-)

Comment: Grrr enter submits...now I know that.  So I made the change you suggested (firefox was complaining before I removed the 'new', now resolved), but I still get the same output as before, no substitution having taken place. Does replace not work the way I think it does, or is there anything you can see in this code that would explain it?  Thanks again!

Comment: Well the regex itself seems to work, at least basically.  Are you sure you've got a container with the "id" value "ELEMENT"? Have you tried doing it with just `jQuery('body')`?

Comment: Yes, I even abstracted the relevant stuff to its own file just to get it working, and alert the result instead of trying to pipe it back into the DIV -- still no substitution takes place. At this point I'm thinking there's something very basic I'm missing, but having looked at it as long as I have keeps the solution elusive.

Comment: Oh, duhh - sorry about that but I just saw the problem.  You've got `^` and `$` anchors around the regex, so it'll only match when the entire string is an IP address!  Just get rid of those and make sure you've got the `g` flag at the end of the regex and it should work.

Comment: If you want to avoid having it match something like 20200100201.2.2.2 then you can put `\b` at the start and end of the pattern. That matches word boundaries, which usually does what you want.

Comment: That was it -- you are the man! Thank you so much for sticking with me through it.